# Completely disable logging outputs on screen

Tags: ros, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to disable the ROS logging in the console completely, but still have the logging to the /rosout topic. I tried these two options:

1. Set `output="log"` in the launch file. This disables the output of Debug, Info and Warning messages but still, Error and Fatal messages are shown in the console.
2. Set the logger level to Fatal but this completely disables the /rosout topic, too.

Are there any other possibilities I could try out?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260476/completely-disable-logging-outputs-on-screen/) by [inspire](https://answers.ros.org/users/28884/inspire/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not a ROS specific solution but you could Pipe the Output to /dev/null, e.g.

```
rosrun your_package your_node > /dev/null
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2017-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inspire](https://answers.ros.org/users/28884/inspire/) on 2017-04-27**:
Ah yeah, that's indeed a solution. But I have another logging framework running that should still be able to log everything to the console.  Sorry, I missed this point.